# why is my data not returning properly from data store in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-datastore

I am making an application and a token returns from the service and I store this token in the dat store. I'm sure I saved the token, but when I get the token, the yield returned should be the token, but something like this is returned.

```
data.util.TokenManager$getToken$$inlined$map$1@26633dd
```

My token should be returned instead, right? for example `2MjqffBhBV64Q7KAC8SfHRwk3XFKsv`

I didn't understand why it was like that. The data store was created as follows.

```
class TokenManager(private val context: Context) {

    companion object {
        private val TOKEN_KEY = stringPreferencesKey("jwt_token")
    }

    fun getToken(): Flow<String?> {
        return context.dataStore.data.map { preferences ->
            preferences[TOKEN_KEY]
        }
    }

    suspend fun saveToken(token: String) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[TOKEN_KEY] = token
        }
    }

    suspend fun deleteToken() {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences.remove(TOKEN_KEY)
        }
    }
}
```

and inside a viewmodel I'm calling the following function for experimentation

```
 fun getToken(){
        val token = tokenManager.getToken()
        println(token.toString())
    }
```

but the data I said above is returning

```
data.util.TokenManager$getToken$$inlined$map$1@26633dd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `getToken()` returns a `Flow<String>`, not a `String`, so you can not simply call `getToken()`. Instead, you should collect all the values from the flow, or get the first value.

**Example (Error):**

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*

suspend fun main() {   
    println(getToken()) // --> Prints: "kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$3@15327b79"
}

fun getToken(): Flow<String?> {
    val flowFromList = listOf("one", "two", "three")
    
    return flowFromList.asFlow()
}
```

**Example (OK)**

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*

suspend fun main() {
    val token = getToken().first() 
    println(token.toString())  // --> Prints: "one"
}

fun getToken(): Flow<String?> {
    val flowFromList = listOf("one", "two", "three")
    
    return flowFromList.asFlow()
}
```